# Creating a SWING app with Eclipse Window Builder

Tags: eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I am using Eclipse Indigo on Mac. I just set up the Window Builder tool however for some reason I can not create a new project with it. I select the Swing Designer -> Application Window option another window pops up and asks me for the source folder, project name etc. but when I try to type a name in the source folder it says file cannot be found and when I try to browse there is nothing to select. Does anyone have an idea about whats going on ? thanks

Comment: So I needed to first create a regular java application and then right click on that project and select the window builder options to get started with the SWING..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to create a Java project then you have to create a source folder and a package, after doing that you can select the created package on the Package explorer and create a new Application Window or JFrame from WindowBuilder menu.

Comment: Where is the WindowBuilder menu?

Answer (score 0):

This  is the snapshots  of my environment. On the eclipse IDE Right click on the  package, Open ---File---New---Other---Then type Jframe. Click on Next and  complete the wizard.

Underneath the capture you can switch between the  source code and  design  view

[snapshots of my environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4D3S.png)

[snapshots of my environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fV1F.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: There is not Jframe option. How can I get the Jframe option?