# Trying to construct a simple GUI in window builder, at a complete loss with regards to what I do next

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

I've been working on a simple GUI for a java program in Eclipse Window Builder, but being a Java novice and very unfamiliar with Eclipse, I have no idea as to how I incorporate my program with the code for the interface, this is what I've got so far

The Autogenerated code

```
public class CPGUI extends Composite {
private Text text_2;
private Text text_1;
private Text text;
private Text text_3;
private Text text_4;
private Text text_5;
private Text text_9;
private Text text_10;
private Text text_11;

private JTextField Cards;  
private JTextField Cleared; 
private JTextField Remaining;
private JTextField TotalMnHr;
private JTextField CompletedMnHr;
private JTextField MnHrRemaining;  

/**
 * Create the composite.
 * @param parent
 * @param style
 */
public CPGUI(Composite parent, int style, Task[] AllTasks, int[] data) {
    super(parent, style);

    setLayout(new GridLayout(6, true));
    new Label(this, SWT.NONE);

    Label lblEstMnhrs = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    lblEstMnhrs.setText("EST. MNHRS");
    new Label(this, SWT.NONE);

    Label lblDates = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    lblDates.setText("DATES");
    new Label(this, SWT.NONE);

    Label lblTasks = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    lblTasks.setText("TASKS");

    Label lblTotal = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    lblTotal.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    lblTotal.setText("TOTAL");

    text_3 = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER);
    text_3.setEditable(false);
    text_3.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

    Label label = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    label.setText("DEADLINE");

    text_9 = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER);
    text_9.setEditable(false);
    text_9.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

    Label lblTotal_1 = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    lblTotal_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    lblTotal_1.setText("TOTAL");

    text = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setEditable(false);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

    Label lblFinished = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    lblFinished.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    lblFinished.setText("FINISHED");

    text_4 = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER);
    text_4.setEditable(false);
    text_4.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

    Label label_1 = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    label_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    label_1.setText("TODAY");

    text_10 = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER);
    text_10.setEditable(false);
    text_10.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

    Label lblCleared = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    lblCleared.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    lblCleared.setText("CLEARED");

    text_1 = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER);
    text_1.setEditable(false);
    text_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

    Label lblRemaining = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    lblRemaining.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    lblRemaining.setText("REMAINING");

    text_5 = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER);
    text_5.setEditable(false);

    Label label_2 = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    label_2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    label_2.setText("MNHRS LEFT");

    text_11 = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER);
    text_11.setEditable(false);
    text_11.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

    Label lblRemaining_1 = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    lblRemaining_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    lblRemaining_1.setText("REMAINING");

    text_2 = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER);
    text_2.setEditable(false);
    text_2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

    Label lblProgress = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    lblProgress.setText("PROGRESS");

    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, SWT.NONE);
    GridData gd_progressBar = new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, true, true, 3, 1);
    gd_progressBar.widthHint = 357;
    progressBar.setLayoutData(gd_progressBar);
    new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(this, SWT.NONE);

    pack();
    setSize(549, 300);         
    setVisible(true);  

    Button btnUpdate = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);

    btnUpdate.setText("UPDATE");

    btnUpdate.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
          switch (e.type) {
          case SWT.Selection:
              int[] data;
                 data = dataCalculator(AllTasks);
                 Cleared = new JTextField(data[1]);
                 Remaining = new JTextField(data[4]);
                 CompletedMnHr = new JTextField(data[3]);
                 TotalMnHr = new JTextField(data[0]);
                 MnHrRemaining = new JTextField(data[2]);
            break;
          }
        }
      });

    new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
}

@Override
protected void checkSubclass() {
    // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
}
```

My Main (in the same java file)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int NumTasks;
NumTasks = NumTasks();

Task[] AllTasks = new Task[NumTasks];
Composite Parent = null;
int Style = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < AllTasks.length; i++)
{
    AllTasks[i] = new Task();
}
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        new CPGUI(AllTasks, dataCalculator(AllTasks)); 
     }
  });
}
```

I'm aware of the fact that I am calling the CPGUI without a composite (whatever that actually is) and some strange int called style, I've no idea what to do, I haven't the foggiest idea as to how SWT works, I assumed window builder would just spit out usable code that I could incorporate into my project.

Comment: You are calling the SWT GUI components in the Swing Event Dispatch Thread... This will not work...

Comment: See: http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet1.java for a very simple demo...

Comment: in this demo the `Shell` window is a `Composite`

Comment: Do you want to build a GUI with or for Eclipse?

Comment: With Eclipse. I'm trying to create an executable program that reads Excel and displays simple statistics using info from the Excel file.

Comment: Your code mixes Swing with SWT. You need to choose one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build a GUI with Eclipse but not for Eclipse, you probably **accidentally chose the SWT instead of the Swing** GUI framework (you have mixed both which [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27754819/6505250) but not as you did it):

See ***[How to create a Swing application with the Eclipse WindowBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8624291/6505250)*** (spoiler: pay attention what you choose in the *New...* dialog)

Comment: Well that clears quite a lot up, pretty sure I intended it to be with swing to start with, but I'm not experienced with eclipse or window builder, so I guess it somehow ended up with SWT, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at this tutorial: [Eclipse RCP](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) to learn about creating GUI within the Eclipse environment. 
I followed that and created a very basic layout within Eclipse. To find more details about working with SWT, try to look at this other tutorial: [SWT Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html). 
This will help you to get into more details about GUI in Eclipse.